# Why does the text keep repeating without a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I am making a code that will give two different types of clocks depending on the radio button selected. When the clock appears, the text saying "Reload the page to go back to clock settings. However, when the 12 hour clock radio button is selected, the text is repeated every second. Is there any way to fix this? And please do not use J Query, I do not know it.

```js
function clock_12() {
 document.write("<div align='center' style = 'background:#420080; color:limegreen'>"+"Reload the page to go back to the clock settings."+"</div>");
 var clocktime = new Date();
 var hours = clocktime.getHours();
 var mins = clocktime.getMinutes();
 var secs = clocktime.getSeconds();
 var ampm = (hours >= 12) ? "P.M." : "A.M.";

 if (hours >= 13) {
  hours -= 12;
 }
 if (hours < 1) {
  hours = 12;
 }
 if (mins < 10) {
  mins = "0" +mins;
 }
 if (secs < 10) {
  secs = "0" +secs;  
 }
 document.write("<div id = 'the_clock' align = 'center' style = 'background:#420080; color:limegreen'></div>");
 var div_clock = document.getElementById("the_clock");
 div_clock.innerHTML = hours + ":" +mins+ ":" +secs+ " " +ampm;
 setTimeout("clock_12()", 1000);
}
function clock_24() {
 var clocktime = new Date();
 var hours = clocktime.getHours();
 var mins = clocktime.getMinutes();
 var secs = clocktime.getSeconds();
 var back = "Reload the page to go back to the clock settings.";
 document.writeln("<div align='center' style = 'background:#420080; color:limegreen'>"+back+"</div>");
 if (mins < 10) {
  mins = "0" +mins;
 }
 if (secs < 10) {
  secs = "0" +secs;  
 }
 document.write("<div id = 'clock' align = 'center' style = 'background:#420080; color:limegreen'</div>");
 var div_clock = document.getElementById("clock");
 div_clock.innerHTML = hours + ":" +mins+ ":" +secs;
 setTimeout("clock_24()", 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<title>12 and 24 Hour Clocks</title>
</head>

<body style="background:limegreen">
<table style="width:50%" align = "center">
 <tr>
  <td><script type = "text/javascript" src = "clock.js"></script></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <br /><br /><td style = "background:#420080; color:limegreen"><label for="clock12">12 Hour Clock</label><input type = "radio" onclick = "clock_12()" id = "clock12" value = "clock12"></td>
  <br /><br /><td style = "background:#420080; color:limegreen"><label for="clock24">24 Hour Clock</label><input type = "radio" onclick = "clock_24()" id = "clock24" value = "clock24"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You call setTimeout with an interval of a second and wonder why the code is repeated every second ???

Comment: In your snippet example, you have syntax errors: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse` and `ReferenceError: clock_12 is not defined`. It's possible there only appear on this example, but check your console for any issues. As it stands right now, your example does not reproduce the issue in your question, as the JS is aborted when the errors are encountered.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Why doesn't the code repeat in the clock_24 function, if it also calls setTimeout with an interval of a second?

Comment: @TimLewis: the point is that here setTimeout() calls a function that calls setTimeout() , recursevly.

Comment: @MarioTrucco Ah, good catch, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the line

```
document.write("<div id = 'clock' align = 'center' style = 'background:#420080; color:limegreen'</div>");
```

Inside your `clock_24` function, which gets called every second because of this: `setTimeout("clock_24()", 1000);`. The same for `clock_12`. So, remove those lines from your functions. Put it outside, like at the beginning of the file `clock.js`. Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

EDIT: sorry, it is more than one line. You have do put all of your `document.write` outside of your functions.

EDIT:  roshen_amin correctly commented that the html needs to be written on click. So the complete solution is to make a function that does the `document.write`, and then `calls clock_24()`/`clock_12()`. On click, call that function instead of `clock_24()`/`clock_12()`. Like that, the html appears when you click, but only the rest of the function is called every second

Comment: if I do that, then the clocks do not show up when I select the radio buttons

Comment: You are right. So, make a function that makes the document.write, and then calls clock_24()/clock_12(). On click, call that function instead of  clock_24()/clock_12(). Like that, the html appears when you click, but only the rest of the function is called every second

Comment: Thanks! That is what I needed!